# laravel 8 Dynamically create Class object based on string

Tags: laravel

Hi  i am trying to show all count for left sidebar menu but unfortunately  i am getting error class not found  **Class 'app/Http/Helpers/Helpers.php' not found** please help me how can id do that thanks.

**app/Http/Helpers/Helpers.php**

```
function NotificationCount()
{
    return Example::where('status', 1)->where( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->latest()->count();
}
```

**leftsidebar**

```
@php
  
$className = 'app/Http/Helpers/Helpers.php';

 $count  = new $className();
  
  return $count->NotificationCount();

@endphp
```

Comment: without .php, $className = 'app\Http\Helpers\Helpers';

Answer (score 1):

Best Practices for custom helpers in Laravel.

Create a `helpers.php` file in your app folder and load it up with composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php" // <---- ADD THIS
    ]
},
```

After adding that to your `composer.json` file, run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

---

add your function

```
function propertyNotificationCount()
{
    return Property::where('status', 1)->where( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->latest()->count();
}
```

in `helper.php` file

Now in any blade file you can call `propertyNotificationCount()` this function.

Comment: sir i have already done it this steps but unfortunately  getting same error.

Comment: If you have already done it, you don't need to use that class. simply `{{  NotificationCount() }}`  call in blade, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not really a good practice to use @php @endphp inside blade templates.

I would probably consider another approach and try to return the notification count from the controller somehow and inside php you could handle more easily the class not found error ( maybe just declare it with use at the begging of the controller and you can use it afterwards )